# Android this (context) giving NullPointerException

Tags: android

Just doing a simple exercise by setting an adapter on a GridView:

```
        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
```

ImageAdapter is another class, as following:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

// ---the images to display---
public Integer[] imageIDs = { R.drawable.one, R.drawable.two,
        R.drawable.three, R.drawable.four, R.drawable.five,
        R.drawable.six };

private Context context;

public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    context = c;
}

// ---returns the number of images---
public int getCount() {
    return imageIDs.length;
}

// ---returns the ID of an item---
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

// ---returns an ImageView view---
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        imageView = new ImageView(context);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(185, 200));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(5, 20, 5, 5);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }
    imageView.setImageResource(imageIDs[position]);
    return imageView;
}
```

}

When I debug the code, app crashes on the gridview.setAdapter line, and report a **java.lang.NullPointerException** on **this**. Any ideas how this can be overcome?

Answer (score 3):

I think that your problem is not the fact that `this` is null, which doesn't make sense, but that `gridView` is null.

It usually happens because of:

1. You didn't call `setContentView()` before `findViewById`.
2. `findViewById` is called with a wrong id.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys but I actually found out the problem. The activity wasn't correctly listed in the Manifest. Thus, the activity's context was becoming null for that reason, I think.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(context));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help guys but I actually found out the problem. The activity wasn't correctly listed in the Manifest. Thus, the activity's context was becoming null for that reason, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(ClassName.this));
```

where ClassName is the class name and extends Android Activity.